# Firestore: Query by item in array of document

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have 2 collections **"photos"** and **"users"** and each document in **"users"** has **one or more photo IDs with an array**.

```
photos > 5528c46b > name: "Photo1"
         a1e820eb > name: "Photo2"
         32d410a7 > name: "Photo3"
```

```
users > acd02b1d > name: "John", photos: ["5528c46b"]
        67f60ad3 > name: "Tom", photos: ["5528c46b", "32d410a7"]
        7332ec75 > name: "Sara", photos: ["a1e820eb"]
        9f4edcc1 > name: "Anna", photos: ["32d410a7"]
```

I want to get **all users who have one or more specific photo IDs**.

Are there any ways to do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> Added 'array-contains' query operator for use with .where() to find documents where an array field contains a specific element.

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js 5.3.0

**Update**: also available in `@google-cloud/firestore`: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/releases/tag/v0.16.0

**Update 2** https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/better-arrays-in-cloud-firestore.html

**Update 3** now available in Admin Node.js SDK v6.0.0 https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/releases

Comment: Welp that took a while :D I was working on a project where I needed this and I'm glad that I lagged back enough for the firebase team to get in the lead :p

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no ways to make a query with few 'array-contains' values.

Comment: @BohdanDidukh have you tried chaining them? .where(..).where(...)?

Comment: @Henry, yes, I tried it. Firebase server responds me with error:
FirebaseError: Invalid query. Queries only support a single array-contains filter.

Comment: is it possible to query array of object using value of object's key like {arrayItems:[{id:123, ....}, {id: 234, ...}]...} and to do something like .where('arrayItems', 'array-contains', 'id=123')? That syntax doesn't seem to work, but I still hope there is a way to do something like that. Please advice

Answer (score 34):

> See [Henry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849222/firestore-query-by-item-in-array-of-document/51511322#51511322), as we've no made Array Contains queries available.

Unfortunately not yet, although it's on our roadmap.

In the meantime, you'll need to use a map instead, in the form of:

```
photos: {
    id1: true
    id2: true
}
```

Now you can find all users with id1 by filtering by `photos.id1 == true`.

Read more about querying such sets in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#top_of_page).

Comment: Is this roadmap published somewhere? Just curious.

Comment: It isn't. We generally don't talk about future features since things can unexpected crop up that change priorities (or even feasibility).

Comment: @DanMcGrath Is there any update to this Feature / Roadmap?

Comment: Firestore won't let me query data this way without indexing every single possible id. Is there some way to not require an index, or to have a dynamic index?

Comment: @KevinBeal have i am also having same question

Comment: @Er.Khatri if your query is simple shouldn't have problem. If your query is compound i.e, adding other params other than a simple where() then you need to index. Firebase already indexes for simple queries.

Comment: @KevinBeal see my comment above

Comment: @TheeBen I don't understand, but if you have an answer, then post it and you'll have my upvote.

Comment: I'm thinking Dan is saying don't use an array field to store the id's, [use an object, or a "map"](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#documents). Seems like no big deal/headache to me. Is there any downside to using the map/object vs array? I can't think of any... just my 2 cents.

Comment: How would you update the array field/object field once created? I am using update() or set() and both seem to overwrite an item in the nested arry/object. How can we prevent this? Any code example? @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: The biggest issue as mentioned by @KevinBeal is that you can index the keys if you need a compound query.  This is a pretty big deal breaker for any advanced query functionality.

Comment: @Man Personson

Even worse. If you want to query by multiple ids then you need to create indexes for all the possible combinations.

Comment: @wube -> This is no longer the case as Cloud Firestore supports queries on arrays now

Comment: @Dan McGrath
It does, but only on a single parameter. You can do `.where('photos', 'array-contains', 'id1')` but you **can't** do `.where('photos', 'array-contains', ['id1', 'id2'])`

Answer (score 5):

Here is a bit of expansion on the answer as some seem to be confused about having to make indexes for each key, Firestore already indexes your data for simple queries thus you can do a simple query like

```
documentReference.where('param','==','value').onSnapshot(...)
```

but you can not do a compound query unless you index your data for those parameters. So you would need indexes to be able to do something like this:

```
 documentReference.where('param','==','value').where(..otherparams...).onSnapshot(...)
```

So as long as you need the photos for an id you can save them as

```
usersCollection :                        (a collection)
    uidA:                                (a document)
         photoField:                     (a field value that is a map or object)
            fieldID1 : true              (a property of the photoField)
            fieldID2 : true              (a property of the photoField)
            etc ...
```

and you can simply query user(s) that have, let's say, fieldID1 in their photoField without needing to form any index and like query below.

```
firestore.doc('usersCollection/uidA').where('photoField.fieldID1','==',true).onSnapshot(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore has now added an 'in' query as of November 2019.
According to [the announcement article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html):

> With the in query, you can query a specific field for multiple values
>   (up to 10) in a single query. You do this by passing a list containing
>   all the values you want to search for, and Cloud Firestore will match
>   any document whose field equals one of those values.

Answer (score 1):

### With Firebase Version 9 (Dec, 2021 Update):

You can use **"array-contains"** with **one single photo document ID** in the **"while()"** to get **all users who have it**:

```js
import {
  query,
  collection,
  where,
  getDocs
} from "firebase/firestore";

// Here
const q = query(
  collection(db, "users"),
  where("photos", "array-contains", "5528c46b")
);
// Here

const usersDocsSnap = await getDocs(q);

usersDocsSnap .forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.data()); // "John's doc", "Tom's doc"
});
```

You can alse use **"array-contains-any"** with **one or more photo document IDs with an array** in the **"while()"** to get **more corresponding users**:

```js
import {
  query,
  collection,
  where,
  getDocs
} from "firebase/firestore";

// Here
const q = query(
  collection(db, "users"),
  where("photos", "array-contains-any", ["5528c46b", "a1e820eb"])
);
// Here

const usersDocsSnap = await getDocs(q);

usersDocsSnap .forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.data()); // "John's doc", "Tom's doc", "Sara's doc"
});
```

Comment: What if ["5528c46b", "a1e820eb"] is in your react state?