# Firebase Firestore Get all document where array contains

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How would I query into Firestore to get all documents where an array contains a certain string?

For example my structure is...

```
/locations
    /{locationId}
          name:"Name of Location"
          description:"Description of Location"
          /lists
               0:"bigList"
               1:"smallList"
               2:"mediumList"
```

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to get from that structure, for example?

Comment: @DougStevenson a specific string in the array.  I noticed firestore has a `whereField(path: FieldPath, isEqualTo: Any)`  I want display results based on if inside the lists array there exists a specific string

Comment: This query is currently not possible with your current structure. But if you change the values under lists to be keys, it **is** possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849222/firestore-query-by-item-in-array-of-document.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so if under lists it was `"bigList": true` ?  How would the query look then?

Comment: Something along the line of `let query = locationsRef.whereField("lists.bigList", isEqualTo: true)`. You can ready more about this structure and the queries here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#top_of_page

Comment: Ahh yes the . notation couldn't figure out how to drill down to that.  Thanks!