# Cloud Firestore: Filter based on object content (via Flutter)

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I have the following Firestore setup in use:

[image]

Now I'd like to receive all documents where the current user (uid given) is in the users object/list.
users is an object of references to thje users collection.

Ideally I would want to use this filter from Flutter with the cloud_firestore package, however for now I'm just interested if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849222/firestore-query-by-item-in-array-of-document) post which explains, that is not currently possible how I imagined it.
I altered my setup to this:

[image]

I can now use this query from Flutter to receive the chats for a given user

```
Firestore.instance
    .collection('chats')
    .where('users.' + _auth.currentUser.uid, isEqualTo: true)
    .snapshots
    .listen((data) {...});
```

I'm also using this rule to make sure that the user can only access the chats in which he is participating:

```
match /chats/{chatId} {
  allow read: if resource.users[request.auth.uid];
  // write rule yet to create
}
```

Comment: Instead of setting the value of the userID to `true` in your map, you should put a timestamp here, as described in the article that I linked.  With your current answer, you will not be able to sort messages by a particular order, based on time.  They'll appear in a random (by document ID) order.

Comment: May I ask, how did you solve the Firestore indexing issue. When adding another .where clause, firestore asks to add an index with the UID value which obviously wouldn't make sense.

Comment: If I wanted to update one of the documents using the 'where' clause, how would that be done? (The doc id is not known, thats why I'm using the 'where' clause)

Comment: Nice, thank you! That saved me quite some time... I can't believe that the flutter firestore has such weak querying capabilities. :(

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  This is possible.  However you will need to store you user references as a map of values and create a reference to query with in your client (based on the user ID).  Take a look at the documentation: [Working with Arrays, Lists and Sets](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#solution_a_map_of_values)