# WHEREIN in Cloud Firestore Database

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

Do we have same as WHEREIN of MySQL in Firestore?
If we don't have such option in Firestore, Then, How to handle it with NodeJS?

I hope I can get my answer soon.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849222/firestore-query-by-item-in-array-of-document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore uses **NoSQL (non-relational) instead of SQL**.

You can fetch data from firestore using Node.js as specific in [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

There is currently no **"IN"** operator in firestore, so the only way to handle this is using `forEach`.

To understand more about JSON format and how to handle it in Node.js, you can read [this](https://www.codementor.io/codementorteam/how-to-use-json-files-in-node-js-85hndqt32).

Comment: If we have array of documents id, then how to get those specified documents? Without foreach.

Comment: There is currently no "IN" operator in firestore. But you can referece this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip)

Comment: array contains operator added:  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js