# Android Firestore query get the id of the document that contains the value in the search

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

[Firestore database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKnkQ.png)

Hello, I just tried to use Firestore. I had some problem when getting document id.

The question is, I want to get a document id (red box) which has value (blue box) in it.

I use the following query:

```
collection("mychannel").whereEqualTo("74wRU4xHrcV9oWAXEkKeRNp41c53")
```

But did not give results.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is answered here: [Firestore: Query by item in array of document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849222/firestore-query-by-item-in-array-of-document)

In summary, don't use arrays to store data in Firestore as the query you are trying to do is not available yet (remember it is still in beta). You should use a Map instead.

Answer (score 3):

As in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays):

> Although Cloud Firestore can store arrays, **`it does not support`** querying array members or updating single array elements.

So there is **no way** in which you can use the following query:

```
collection("mychannel").whereEqualTo("74wRU4xHrcV9oWAXEkKeRNp41c53")
```

If you only want to get the entire `userId` array you need to iterate over a `Map` like this:

```
collection("mychannel").document("1fReXb8pgQvJzFdzpkSy").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = document.getData();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getKey().equals("userId")) {
                        Log.d("TAG", entry.getValue().toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

But note, even if `userId` object is stored in the database as an array, `entry.getValue()` returns an `ArrayList`, not an `array`.

So the output will be:

```
[74wRU4xHrcV9oWAXEkKeRNp41c53]
```

A better approach will be if you consider this alternative database structure, where each user id is the key in a map and all values are true:

```
userId: {
    "74wRU4xHrcV9oWAXEkKeRNp41c53": true,
    "AdwF...": true,
    "YsHs...": true
}
```