# Firestore- Flutter array contains

Tags: dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46849222/firestore-query-by-item-in-array-of-document) and JavaScript supports `'array-contains'` but what about flutter? Is there any way to query array that contains? Or flutter not support this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `array-contains` feature was added in version 0.8.0 of the FlutterFire library.

See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20489#issuecomment-419181186

Answer (score 2):

Today I discover that they add array-contains to the plugin in version 0.8.0:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/CHANGELOG.md

For iOS you should update the pod with `pod update Firebase/Firestore`

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do right now is to use a firebase cloud functions to achieve whatever isnt yet available for the flutter firestore library. Thats what i intend to do when its time to refactor.

Comment: Thanks for comment great idea I’ll check that!