# Firebase: query by array field itself(not by an item of the array)

Tags: arrays, flutter

in my 'rooms' collections, each document has the fields like the following,
{
   "createdAt" : 2020.6.4 12:00,
   "titleArray" : ["icecream", "summer"]
}

And I want to query to check if a collection contains a document with ["icecream", "summer"] as "titleArray" field, I couldn't find a way to query by an array field itself. In other words, is there a way to passing in an array directly?

Comment: Please refer to this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/51925158/9206337

Comment: This solution seems like to find w.r.t the value 'inside' an array field. I want to filter according to the 'array field' itself..

Comment: The where query would be used here but i am not sure if it accepts a non literal as a value comparison. Heres the link https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html